# Rails 4 smtp Openssl error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, openssl, actionmailer

We are using mandrill in our Rails app and just upgraded from Rails 3 to Rails 4.2.3. For some reason, now we are getting this error `OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read finished A` whenever ActionMailer tries to send emails.

Our app is hosted on Heroku and the ssl certificate is a wildcard. I honestly only know what I've read from other people with openssl problems when it comes to anything dealing with ssl, so I really don't even know where to start.

Here's the current config for ActionMailer and Mandrill:

```
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
      :port =>           '587',
      :address =>        'smtp.mandrillapp.com',
      :user_name =>      ENV['MANDRILL_USERNAME'],
      :password =>       ENV['MANDRILL_APIKEY'],
      :domain =>         'heroku.com',
      :authentication => :plain
  }
```

Is there any configuration option that changed that we may be missing?

Answer (score 0):

Switch:

```
authentication => :plain
```

with:

```
:authentication => :login
```

and add:

```
:enable_starttls_auto => true
```

Comment: I'm giving it a shot. I'll let you know how it goes!